# Mongodb aggregation - return rows which were used during aggregation in addition to total sum

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

What I have is daily search statistics like:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f59bce7d84f992eb755992"),
    "date" : ISODate("2014-02-02T23:00:00Z"),
    "municipality" : "Viborg",
    "keyword" : "windows",
    "amount" : 10
}
```

which means there were 10 searches on 'windows' on this day.

What I want to achieve:
aggregate amount of searches on word in some date ranges( which I can do at the moment), but in addition I want to have all rows which were used in aggregation in json array. Thats because "keyword" here is using mongodb text indexes http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/ with stemming etc, so I want to aggregate "window"/"windows"... into one value but also has possibility to view which words were counted.

Should I work with map reduce emit function here?

Comment: Can you show your current aggregation query?

Comment: Can you clarify? How will you aggregate together the documents by stem if the stem isn't stored on the document? It looks like you should just add a `keyword_stem` field to the document and aggregate on that, then `$addToSet` the `keyword` to get a list of keywords in the result group document.

Comment: I wanted to use query in mapReduce which hits text search so I get window/windows.. rows, then emit them somehow and sum their "amount". But...  at least for my solution its not better in any way than just return all rows and sum value manually.